# Consume json object into a class with json array as hashset

Tags: java, json, hashset

**Question is, how do I read the array in json object to set of authorities automatically?**

I am trying to convert a json object received in rest body in an object of class USER:

```
public class User {
    public String userid;
    public String password;
    private String fullname;
    private String email;
    private String websettings;
    private String productionlines;
    private String language;
    private String statustracking;
    private String createdate;
    public Set<Authority> authorities;
}
```

Authority.java:

```
public final class Authority implements Serializable {


    private String authority;
    private String userid;

    public Authority(String authority, String userid) {
        this.authority = authority;
        this.userid = userid;
    }}
```

This is the json object I get:

```
{
   "userid":"xx.xx",
   "password":"",
   "fullname":"asdfasdf",
   "email":"ali@sdf.com",
   "websettings":"this is setting",
   "productionlines":"production lines.",
   "createdate":"1234345",
   "statustracking":"status tracking...",
   "authorities" : [
    "user", "admin"
    ]
}
```

and this is how I am consuming it:

```
   public User createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.createUser(user.getUserid(), user.password, user.getFullname(), user.getEmail(), null, getUserAuthorities(user));
    }
```

Comment: Is `Authority` a class or an enum?

Comment: unfortunately a class

Comment: Can you paste its structure?

Comment: I have added the code to authority.java in the question.

Comment: If you want to use a class in a `Set`, it needs to have `hashCode` and `equals` overridden.

Comment: If you are using jackson, it won't be possible to automatically convert the list of strings coming in `authorities` field to Authority class objects. You'll have to handle that in your code. This may require creating a different class as parameter to `createUser`. This class will be identical to `User`, except for the authorities field. You'll have to convert this to `User` programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try with below JSON

```
{
        "userid" : "xx.xx",
        "password" : "",
        "fullname" : "asdfasdf",
        "email" : "ali@sdf.com",
        "websettings" : "this is setting",
        "productionlines" : "production lines.",
        "createdate" : "1234345",
        "statustracking" : "status tracking...",
        "authorities" : [{
                "authority" : "user",
                "userid" : "userID"
            }
        ]
    }
```

and provide necessary constructor, getter/setter and override necessary methods(hashcode/equals)